# I accessed my boss's private Facebook messages, and found out she is trying to fire me. How do I proceed?

Tags: professionalism, human-resources, manager, social-media

I had been asked to do a bit of social media work. I gained access to my boss's personal Facebook messages, since the business page is linked to it.

I have been having a rough time at work, and went through her private messages to see what she has been saying about me. It turns out she's been trying to get me fired.

I want to report this to HR, but I'm scared it could backfire on me for snooping into my boss's private messages.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Wow.... you should have not looked into someones private messages, even though the account used is your boss'es

Comment: you should be fired for that, so karma strikes again?

Comment: Also, your question says "am I allowed to go through the messages" when you clearly already did that.... this question should have been asked previous to you getting the account.

Comment: Tough call.  Personally, I'd fire both of you.  You for exceeding your authority, and your boss for being stupid enough to give you access to their personal account rather than delegating the company page to you.

Is your boss the owner?  If they are, you have no recourse.  Pack up and walk away.

Comment: Yeah so going back a few months my manager was fixing a phone for my coworker and she went through her messages as well then showed my boss and ended up getting her fired.

Comment: Whenever my manager messages my boss she always uses the wink emoji and seems like she gets everything done her own way in the business because my boss just loves her

Comment: @unknownunknown then *why* would you like to repeat that situation? Knowing that you should not have read the messages in the first place.

Comment: Part of your manager's job is to make assessments of people she supervises.  She thinks you are not cutting it, and wants you fired, apparently.  What, exactly, about that would you report to Human Resources? Even if you or higher-ups disagree, I'm not seeing what is inappropriate about that.

Comment: I'd start looking for a new job ASAP. Aside from knowing that your boss is trying to get you fired, your boss sounds both incompetent and vindictive and not someone I would want to work for.

Comment: Ive done nothing but put my head down and work hard but apparently I've just been on my phone

Comment: @unknownunknown this shows more about your character than your managers. Is it not possible that when your boss sees you, you are actually on you phone? That doesn't mean you aren't working your ass off. It is possible that she has seen you on your phone multiple times and actually has reason to believe this is an issue. So your boss may not be lying yo oyu

Comment: @unknownunknown do not turn in your notice, find another job *FIRST*, **then** resign. Learn from your mishap here.

Comment: The "boss" in your question went from "his" to "her" in the same sentence, so I have edited the whole description to use feminine pronouns. If this is a mistake, please clarify and I will edit it for you, or, of course, you can do it yourself.

Comment: What does "trying to get me fired" mean? Does it mean they're going through what can arguably be considered formal processes to fire you (or just honestly discussing your performance with higher-ups)? Or does it mean they're actively trying to sabotage you by e.g. making up obvious lies?

Comment: If "apparently you've just been on your phone" one thing you *can* do is preemptively make sure you don't have your phone on you at work. If you get called in to "discuss" it you can say "I don't even bring my phone in the office because I don't want to be perceived as someone who does just that.  Even so, you're still pretty screwed.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet, You don't see a problem with using Facebook to discuss (possibly sensitive) information about an employee's performance? Another interesting question is who was the manager discussing this with? Their boss, OP's coworkers, random friends, etc?

Comment: @mikeazo - maybe that comment should fall under my answer, instead of the question. If the person is sending ***private*** messages on FB, I'm not sure how that's less professional than any other means of private communication - personal email, text, phone call. I do think it should probably be kept on work communication channels, but, again, what is done on a ***private*** communication system is no one's business, at all, unless it is information (like government administration) that is, by definition, public. It's not like the boss was posting it on their FB wall. Private messages/email.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The only way to proceed is to look for another job.  You know your manager wants you gone. Usually, such wishes are supported by a company.

There's nothing to report to HR, because a manager deciding an underling should be fired is part of their job.  There's nothing wrong with that, even if you don't like it.

There's also nothing to report to HR because you went through that person's personal messages on Facebook.  I'd have to think, even as dumb as they were to give you that access, it would be considered an abuse of access they gave you, and that could get you fired.  If you mention you did it, you're pretty much hanging a "fire me" sign on yourself.

Finally, you do deserve to be fired for that, technically.  It is unethical for you to violate someone's privacy like that.  It's best to get out while you might still get some kind of neutral recommendation or background check response.  If anyone finds out that this was done in a work environment, you'll never get anything but a very negative response from this company if a future employer makes even basic inquiries.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, will be handing in my notice tomorrow.

Comment: @unknownunknown - Look for another job, first. Finding employment is much easier if you currently have a job.  Companies and HR departments have an almost knee-jerk aversion to people who are currently "between jobs."  If the current employer pulls the trigger, so be it, but I'd hold off notice until I'm ready to move, unless the situation is so toxic you just can't stay.

Comment: @unknownunknown do not turn in your notice, find another job *FIRST*, **then** resign.  Learn from your mishap here.

Comment: I am surprised by the number of votes for this answer, as telling someone they deserve to be fired is in no way being nice.

Comment: it's neither nice nor mean. It's an opinion of what standard practice. This is just stirring up dissent.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep You are one of my favs here, but how on earth is this   *"Finally, you deserve to be fired for that"* in any way nice?

Comment: @MisterPositive Thanks.  I see it as neutral.  If we say that you can't declare an opinion that some actions deserve termination, then our advice isn't useful or honest. Polo didn't say he's a bad person or that he should have something horrible happen to him. He merely said that his actions warrant certain consequences.

Comment: @ChristopherEstep I see your point, would probably not have been so jolting IMHO if it weren't **BOLD**.

Comment: @MisterPositive - I did not call the OP anything horrible, I did not state that they were a bad person.  I stated that their actions were completely unethical, which they were. Should that be sugar-coated?  We had another user, previously, who was canned for financial misdeeds. Some actions in the workplace warrant firing. If I posted that I punched a co-worker, many might empathize and sympathize with **why** I did it, but the blunt assessment of "you **deserve** to be fired for punching a co-worker" would be a pretty objective assessment. Some things are universally "verboten."  This is one.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I see your point.  Sometimes though its not what you say but how you say it that matters.  :-)

Comment: @MisterPositive - a similarly objective assessment of my communication style might be "you tend to be unnecessarily glib and blunt, at times."

Answer (score 13):

> How do I proceed?

You know your boss is trying to get you fired, **start looking for new employment ASAP** and remember its always easier to find a job when you are currently employed.

Going to HR at this point is fruitless as it most likely will result in nothing more than a write up for you both, and your boss will now be **more inclined to get rid of you** then before.

As a piece of friendly advise and not to scold, but do learn from this. *Never* go through someone's personal information in **any** format again.

Comment: Downvoter's please elaborate so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should **not look into someone's private messages**, even if they gave you *some* access to their accounts. This would be considered highly unprofessional in most businesses.

Also, you comment that a previous coworker got fired for disclosing similar information, so *why* would you repeat such situation?

Now, this is clearly some information you were not supposed to know, so technically there is no correct way of proceeding. However, given this information it would be wise to start looking for *another job*.

Answer (score 4):

You found out your manager is trying to get you fired, so the only thing you should do is start looking for another job. The source of information being her private Facebook messages is irrelevant to what *you* do. From your perspective, the situation would be the same if you had found out through other means, such as eavesdropping on her phone call, or due to her wrongly forwarding you an email, etc.

Your gut instinct is correct, nothing good will come out of going to HR. Making decisions to fire people is more or less a part of a manager's job, so complaining to HR that you found out your manager is doing her job (by unauthorized access to her private Facebook messages, no less) will not only make you look silly, but also give them evidence to support their decision.